# check whether the lines meet or not and apply numpy function accordingly

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function that tells the meeting point if it exists, and otherwise finds the point that is closest to both the lines. So, if the lines meet, apply np.linalg.solve, otherwise np.linalg.lstsq.

---

```
def almost_meeting_lines(a1, b1, a2, b2):
    a = np.array([[-a1,1],[-a2,1]])
    b = np.array([b1,b2])
    if a1==a2:
        (x,y) = np.linalg.lstsq(a,b,rcond=None)[0]
    else:
        (x,y)= np.linalg.solve(a,b)
    return (x,y),a1==a2

a1=1
a2=2
b1=2
b2=-2
(x, y), exact = almost_meeting_lines(a1, b1, a1, b2)
print(exact)
if exact:
    print(f"Lines meet at x={x} and y={y}")
else:
    print(f"Closest point at x={x} and y={y}")
```

---

The problem I'm facing is, the function always return true whether a1(slope of line1) is equal to a2(slope of line2) or not AND always applies np.linalg.solve().

Answer (score 0):

Typo in the function call.

`(x, y), exact = almost_meeting_lines(a1, b1, a1, b2)`

should be

`(x, y), exact = almost_meeting_lines(a1, b1, a2, b2)`